# Can I have multiple controllers in the admin of my PyroCMS module?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pyrocms

Let's say I have a module called `xyz`.

My admin controller is here: `cms/addons/shared_addons/modules/xyz/controllers/admin.php`
And is accessed as follows:

- `http://whatever.com/admin/xyz`
- `http://whatever.com/admin/xyz/some_method`
- `http://whatever.com/admin/xyz/ijk`

Can I create a controller that will let me use the following URLs?

- `http://whatever.com/admin/xyz/subcontroller/`
- `http://whatever.com/admin/xyz/subcontroller/a_method`
- `http://whatever.com/admin/xyz/subcontroller/b_method`

If so, how would I name the controller file and class?

I've tried creating `admin_subcontroller.php` and calling the class `Admin_Subcontroller` or `Admin_Xyz_Subcontroller` but neither works.

Cheers!

Comment: Would it be best to employ the `_remap()` function and handle this myself?

Answer (score 1):

Add a file to your config folder called routes.php and the add something like the following:

```
$route['module/admin/subcontroller(:any)?'] = 'admin_subcontroller$1';
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Not tested this yet but it seems like the right way to go about this. Cheers!